# Как читать кадры видео в байтовом режиме?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

Из видео (mp4) необходимо получить некий набор кадров.
Сначала реализовывал так:

- каждое изображение сохранял как отдельный jpeg-файл
- затем открывал этот файл и читал в байтовом режиме

Но условия задачи запрещают использовать дополнительные файлы.

Какие есть способы это реализовать?

Каждый кадр представляет собой массив типа `ndarray`, пробовал преобразовывать его с помощью метода `ndarray.tobytes()`, но это не вариант, так как результат получается другой.

Answer (score 2):

[Пример из официальной документации](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # processing a frame here ...

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```